# swift получение push токена в background

Tags: swift

Получаю токен для пуш уведомлений, отправляю на сервер, сервер шлет пуши - все ок, но, иногда пуш токен меняется и уведомления не доходят (при условии, что юзер не будет заходить в приложение и оно не сможет обновить пуш токен на сервере).

Проблема в том, что юзер может долгое время не зходить в приложение, а пуши слать надо

Можно ли в бэкграунде запросить пуш токен и отправить на сервер? Я думал делать тихие уведомления, но опять же, когда токен поменяется тихое уведолмение не придет. Есть еще какие-то варианты ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Других вариантов получения токена - **нет**

Пуш токен может меняться лишь при переустановке приложения, в таких случаях вам нужно работать с новым сгенерированным